# iOS-style scrolling in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need some script or solution to reach such one scrolling mode like in iOS (or OSX Lion).
I've got a Mac with Lion, so most of scripts seem to be so working, but it's needed for all OSes and web browsers.

I mean something that divs will be scrollable with custom scrollbar, which will cover (as overlay) the content! Like here: [For all not-iOS-users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsq5C.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't want to use the native scrolling method on your website? You want to use a separate solution? http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Answer (score 0):

Any of these links will do for you as a solution to get a coustom scroll bar for divs.If you look carefully all these sites have demos, Check out:

http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

http://13thparallel.com/archive/dhtml-scrollbars/

Comment: I found solution named nanoScroller.js (http://jamesflorentino.com/jquery.nanoscroller/) but cannot well install it ;/

Comment: Those solutions are truly ancient. One of them doesn't even work properly anymore; the other doesn't support scrolling events, only drag. There are two or three good scrollers for imitating iOS bars today: [antiScroll](http://learnboost.github.io/antiscroll/), [nanoScroller](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/), [lionBars](http://charuru.github.io/lionbars/), [Nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) (I dislike the momentum implementation)...